# Delphi 10.4 FMX UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, delphi, 64-bit, firemonkey

I am trying to build my app for Android 64 bit with Delphi 10.4.
I have been building for Android 32 bit successfully so far. However Google Play requires 64 bit release.
Here is the error I am getting.

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewObjectV called with pending exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.embarcadero.BiKolay-Cnwx1cniUgstNJrRAjvrEQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.embarcadero.BiKolay-Cnwx1cniUgstNJrRAjvrEQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.embarcadero.BiKolay-Cnwx1cniUgstNJrRAjvrEQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so"

P.s. Blank 64-bit app that doesn't have any libs in it works just fine. But I don't need that.
How can I deploy my app to my phone as an 64 bit app with Delphi FMX?

Comment: *couldn't find 'libopencv_java3.so* seems to be a pretty clear error message. It's not finding the 64-bit version of a required library.

Comment: OK I got libopencv_java3.so file. Where exactly is this supposed to be put? I tried putting in C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\lib\android64\release\arm64-v8a but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing you're putting it in the wrong place. I find files like that in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-21.0.40680.4203\android-ndk-r21\platforms\android-26\arch-x86_64\usr\lib64 (I've used `android-ndk-r21\platforms\android-26` as an example, but there are multiple Android versions in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\` that might be applicable depending on what you're targeting.

Comment: There was no NDK folder with 21.0 but There was a NDK folder for Embarcadero/Studio/20.0 , I copied that folder and pasted into the Folder for 21.0. 
I removed my jar files from Android 32-bit , and added them to Android 64-bit via Delphi IDE.
Now the opencv error is gone. But I'm getting ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener"
error instead. Any idea?

Comment: No, don't copy to the 21 folder. Just use the 20 folder - you don't have Android 21 instealled. Use the one that **matches your Android version**, as I said in my previous comment. You can't just mix and match Android version files at will.

Comment: Actually I was talking about the Version with Embarcadero. I used 20.0 before , now I'm using 21.0. Anyway, I'm targetting Android 29 which I already installed. So I copied my opencv.so file in a folder path like 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-17b_20.0.34749.6593\platforms\android-29\arch-x86_64\usr\lib64'. Any idea what can solve the 'OnApplyWindowInsetsListener' issue?

Comment: As I have no idea what "issue" you're talking about, I'm afraid I can't offer any help there.

Comment: Also, what you *should* be doing is re-running the Delphi installer and choosing to install the proper Androiid NDK that ocmes with that version, instead of just deciding you can copy files into and out of various installations. This not only makes sure you get the proper versions of the files, but it makes sure that the IDE is correctly configured to find and use them.

Comment: Using IDE's Tools--> Manage Platforms , I installed 'AndroidNDK-21-21.0.40680.4203' now and 'AndroidSDK-2525-21.0.40680.4203' . And I went to the folder 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository\AndroidNDK-21-21.0.40680.4203\android-ndk-r21\platforms\android-29\arch-x86_64\usr\lib64' and put my libopencv_java3.so file  in there. But still getting ..... /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so" . Would you tell me what else I can try? @KenWhite

Comment: I told you before you **cannot** just move files around however you want. Install the **proper version** of the SDK, and it will have the necessary files without your having to copy anything. If you insist on corrupting your installation by putting files wherever you feel like, you're never going to make any progress. To repeat, **DO NOT** copy or move any files that aren't already in the installation.

Comment: First , There is nothing has been copied, it is a brand new installation. Second, after seeing that it threw the error 'libopencv_java3.so' was not found. I copied the so file in the folder of NDK which didn't bring any solution too. That one was copied from openCV folder I had downloaded not from the previous installation. To not repeat again NOTHING has been copied which were not already there at first.

Comment: In your previous comment (just above my last comment), you wrote *' and put my libopencv_java3.so file in there*, which tells me you've copied a file. If that's not what you meant, why did you write it?  **DO NOT COPY OR MOVE ANY FILES**. Install the proper version of the NDK and it will already have a copy of the file without your doing anything at all. For the third time, **YOU CANNOT MIX AND MATCH FILES AT WILL. IT WILL CORRUPT YOUR INSTALLATION.. DO NOT COPY OR MOVE FILES.** Maybe you'll listen this time.

Comment: At first a project that is fine with 32 bit, crashed with 64 bit. Then I saw 'libopencvxx.so' was not found in the folder lib64. Then I found the related so file and put it in the folder lib64 it asks me to put. Again got the same error like I put nothing in the related folder. I took the installation steps which got me NDK 21. It didn't work again pointing no opencv so file was found in the folder lib64. Then I copied 'libopencvxx.so' to the folder which didn't solve anything again. SO IT DOESN'T WORK WITH OR WITHOUT LIBOPENCV STAYING IN MY FOLDER.This way, maybe this time you can understand

Comment: Dont you have to add that file to the "Deployment" page so it will be in the app when it runs?

Comment: Thank you @DougRudd it is at least something to be checked before the deployment. This can help someone find a solution in the future. I will write down what solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

What solved for me is

1. Make sure your Project -->Deployment --> Android 64 has the so file with its local path and remote path got set.
2. Find the Application.mk file and make sure your APP_ABI looks like mine:

APP_ABI := arm64-v8a

3. Ignore the ignorants that lead you in the wrong way.